# access returned data from node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, node-modules

I am creating a node module (first time!) and I have this code:

```
exports.myFunc = function(string) {
   if (!string) {
      return false
   } else {
      return true
   }
}
```

and then on my server when I test my module, I try this:

```
var test_mod = require('test-xxx-nodemodule')
let string = "test!"
test_mod.myFunc(string)
```

now what I want to do is when I call `test_mod.myFunc(string)`, I want to be able to check if it returns true or false from my server. What I've tried is:

```
let results = test_mod.myFunc(string)
if (results === true) {
   console.log("it is returned true")
} else {
   console.log("it is returned false")
}
```

But it tried these before it returns the results from `test_mod.myFunc`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define your module like this

```js
module.exports = function(string) {/* I changed this line*/
   if (!string) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

And test your module with

```js
const test_mod = require('./your-module.js');/*And changed this line*/
let string = "Hello World !";
if(test_mod(string)){
    console.log("it is returned true");
}else{
    console.log("it is returned false");
}
```

Just tested with node.js v16.13.1, that seems to work

Comment: this opened my mind, cool! The only thing is, it isn't actually checking based on the returned value of true or false. I am trying to have it read the returned value. does that make sense? nonetheless, thanks 4 sharing

Comment: @wonkydev If you're talking about the `if`, I actually check the returned value of the function : `if(test_mod(string))` is the same thing as `if(test_mod(string) === true)`. In this case, it's not really usefull to use `=== true`. You can get the returned value of the function with `let result = test_mod(string);`.
You're welcome !

Comment: OHH solid okay. Just tried it to see it for myself. You're a lifesaver, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
var test_mod = require('test-xxx-nodemodule')
```

to this:

```
var test_mod = require('./test-xxx-nodemodule')
```

Note:index.js and test-xxx-nodemodule.js are in same level

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzGWY.jpg)

Comment: thanks for sharing! This helps me test it locally easier!